# jquery onload prettyphoto

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

How do I get this to load onload instead of when clicked?

Comment: if prettyPhoto is a plugin, you should give the url to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [prettyPhoto documentation](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone//documentation/), you can do any of the following directly in your script.

```
$.prettyPhoto.open('images/fullscreen/image.jpg','Title','Description');
$.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
$.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
$.prettyPhoto.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto().click();
```

That should trigger a click event on the link after attaching the prettyPhoto events to it. I imagine it'll break if you have more than one prettyPhoto link on the page, though.

Comment: Only $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto() is enought, otherwise you will open 2 modals. =)

Answer (score 0):

Put `onLoad="$.prettyPhoto.open('images/fullscreen/image.jpg','Title','Description');"` in the body tag, easy peasy.

Comment: jquery ready event is incompatible with the 'onLoad' attribute.